# Calculate third point of isosceles triangle given two points and distance

Tags: geometry, triangles, fixed-points

Calculate third point of isosceles triangle given two points and distance
Given values -
[image: givenvalues]

Problem image - [image: Isosceles Triangle]

My solution to the problem,[image: my solution]

After substituting values,
[image: Isosceles Triangle after substituting values]

But, I had no idea on how to find the point A(xa, xb)?
please help me to find the solution

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hints:  Construct the perpendicular bisector from $A$ to $\overline{BC}.$  Denote the intersection point as $D$, which will be exactly in the middle of line $\overline{BC}.$  Since the lengths of $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{BD}$ are known, so is the length of $\overline{AD}.$  Also, the slope of $\overline{AD}$ is the negative reciprocal of the  slope of $\overline{BC}.$

Comment: @user2661923 : there is a simpler advice to give: A is one of the 2 Intersections of the circles with centers B and C and radius 5.

Comment: @JeanMarie Simpler to give, but perhaps not simpler to implement.  The goal is to get the $(x,y)$ coordinates of $A$, and it is reasonable to assume that the entire topic is fairly new to the original poster.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks, We can find point A by considering it to be the centre of a circle containing two points B and C.  [how-do-you-find-the-center-of-a-circle-given-two-points](https://byjus.com/question-answer/how-do-you-find-the-center-of-a-circle-given-two-points/)

Comment: @user2661923 In fact, having thought again to your hints, I realize that you were right, not only from a didactic point of view, but also as you say it simpler to implement.

Comment: The height (length of altitude) $9.33...$ you obtain is visibly too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, there a way to obtain the coordinates of point $A$ without solving a quadratic equation. See program below (sorry, in Matlab, but so cousin to Python...).

1. Compute vector $\vec{DB}=\frac12 \vec{CB}=\pmatrix{r_1\\s_1}=\pmatrix{\tfrac12(x_B-x_C)\\ \tfrac12(y_B-y_C)}$ and its norm.
2. Deduce from this norm the length $\ell$ of altitude $AD$ by using Pythagoras in right triangle $ADB$.
3. Then, due to vector equation :

$$\vec{DA}=\ell \vec{V} \ \ \iff \ \ A=D+\ell \vec{V}$$

the coordinates of $A$ are :

$$\begin{cases}x_A&=&x_D+ \ell r\\ y_A&=&y_D+ \ell s\end{cases}$$

where midpoint $D$ has coordinates $$D=\pmatrix{\tfrac12(x_B+x_C)\\ \tfrac12(y_B+y_C)} $$

and $V=\pmatrix{r\\s}$ is defined in two steps :

- first, we set $$ \vec{W} = \pmatrix{-s_1\\r_1}$$

(please note that $\vec{W}$ is an orthogonal vector to vector $\vec{DB}$)

- then the normalized vector $\vec{V}$ is obtained by dividing  $\vec{W}$ by its norm (its length).

Matlab program:

> ```
> xB=9.48;yB=12.175;xC=9.877;yC=8.591;
> xD=(xB+xC)/2;yD=(yB+yC)/2;   % midpoint D
> r1=(xC-xB)/2;s1=(yC-yB)/2;   % vector DB
> DB=sqrt(r1^2+s1^2);          % length DB
> el=sqrt(5^2-DB^2);           % length of altitude AD
> Wx=-s1;Wy=r1;                % vector orth. to vector DB
> Vx=Wx/DB;Vy=Wy/DB;           % unit vector (length W = length DB)
> xA=xD+el*Vx;                 % 14.314
> yA=yD+el*Vy;                 % 10.896
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution to the problem:
[Mathematical Expression Problem Solving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjiYc.png)

Python code to check output:

```
    def distance(p1, p2):
        x1 = p1[0]
        y1 = p1[1]
        x2 = p2[0]
        y2 = p2[1]
        return math.sqrt(math.pow(x1-x2,2) + math.pow(y1-y2,2))

    def findCenter(p1, p2, radius):
        x1 = p1[0]
        y1 = p1[1]
        x2 = p2[0]
        y2 = p2[1]

        c1 = math.pow(x1,2) - math.pow(x2,2) + math.pow(y1,2) - math.pow(y2,2)
        c2 = 2*(x1-x2)
        c3 = 2*(y1-y2)

        d1 = c1/c3 
        d2 = c2/c3

        a = 1 + math.pow(d2, 2)
        b = -2*x1 - 2*(d1)*(d2) + 2*(d2)*y1
        c = math.pow(x1,2) + math.pow(y1,2) + math.pow(d1, 2) - 2*d1*y1 - math.pow(radius,2)

        x3_1 = (-b + math.sqrt(math.pow(b,2) - 4*a*c))/(2*a)
        x3_2 = (-b - math.sqrt(math.pow(b,2) - 4*a*c))/(2*a)

        y3_1 = (c1 - c2*x3_1)/c3
        y3_2 = (c1 - c2*x3_2)/c3

        p3_1 = [x3_1, y3_1]
        p3_2 = [x3_2, y3_2]
        return p3_1, p3_2

    # For your question
    p1 = [9.48, 12.175]
    p2 = [9.877, 8.591]
    radius = 5
    p3_1, p3_2 = findCenter(p1, p2, radius)

    print("Answer for your question")
    print(p3_1)
    print(p3_2)
    print("distance p1, p3_1 = ", distance(p1, p3_1))
    print("distance p2, p3_1 = ", distance(p2, p3_1))
    print("distance p1, p3_2 = ", distance(p1, p3_2))
    print("distance p2, p3_2 = ", distance(p2, p3_2))

    # For Byjus question how-do-you-find-the-center-of-a-circle-given-two-points
    p1 = [5,4]
    p2 = [3,6]
    radius = 10
    p3_1, p3_2 = findCenter(p1, p2, radius)

    print("\n\nFor Byjus question")
    print(p3_1)
    print(p3_2)
    print("distance p1, p3_1 = ", distance(p1, p3_1))
    print("distance p2, p3_1 = ", distance(p2, p3_1))
    print("distance p1, p3_2 = ", distance(p1, p3_2))
    print("distance p2, p3_2 = ", distance(p2, p3_2))
```

**Ouput:-**

> Answer for your question
> [14.313767402298724, 10.896448984015787]
> [5.043232597701277, 9.869551015984205]
> distance p1, p3_1 =  5.000000000000002
> distance p2, p3_1 =  5.0
> distance p1, p3_2 =  5.000000000000003
> distance p2, p3_2 =  5.0
> .
> For Byjus question
> [11.0, 12.0]
> [-3.0, -2.0]
> distance p1, p3_1 =  10.0
> distance p2, p3_1 =  10.0
> distance p1, p3_2 =  10.0
> distance p2, p3_2 =  10.0
> Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Please, have a look at the alternative solution I just wrote.